# Passing BuildContext to non builder methods

Tags: android, ios, flutter, web, dart

I was wondering if passing around BuildContext objects that we receive in the build method is a good idea? Basically pass it to places that are non-builder methods.

For example, I may pass it to my ViewModel in the case of the Provider package. Is it a good thing to do?

Or will it have repercussions?

Answer (score 0):

Passing `BuildContext` around is generally a bad idea.

This object is not made to be passed around. If you need a `BuildContext`, instead create a new one (using a custom `StatelessWidget` or `Builder`).

Failing to do so may cause bugs that are hard to debug (such that causing a `ProviderNotFoundException`), and creating a new `BuildContext` instead of reusing an existing one can improve performances.

Comment: The specific issue I have is that I have a ViewModel class that needs access to this context to show snackbar.

But this ViewModel is not a widget class.
So what do I do?

Comment: Don't make your ViewModel show snackbars. Instead make it observable, and have the View listen to the object and show snackbars when needed

Comment: Even then I would need access to Context, where do I get it from?

Comment: Builder/StatelessWidget